# Filter NSArray of strings when portion of string is empty using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

I would like to filter out items of an array of strings where the right portion of a string is empty using NSPredicate but my knowledge of NSPredicate is limited.

The strings look should like `{"0,General", "1,Sports", "2,Entertainment"}` etc.

I want to filter out cases where you have something like: `"0,"` or even `","`

So if I had `{"0,General", "1,Sports", "0,","2,Entertainment"}`, I would want to filter out the flawed category "0,".

I know I can filter out entirely empty strings with something like the following:

```
NSArray *filteredcats = [mycats filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                         [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```

How can I filter out strings in the array where anything to the right of a comma in the string is empty?

Comment: Just iterate over the array and filter using string comparison operators and add the required elements to your output array.  Using a predicate doesn't give any performance advantage

Comment: Looks like you aren't representing your data correctly and are now relying on hacky methods to manage that data.  I would rethink how you are holding the data; for example by keeping an array of custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use regular rexpressions for this,

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@",First",@"0,General",@"1,Sports",@"2,Entertainment",@"3,",@","];
NSString *regex = @"^\\d,\\w+$";
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
NSArray *matches = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

NSLog(@"matches: %@", matches);
```

```
matches: (
    "0,General",
    "1,Sports",
    "2,Entertainment"
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant to filter out cases where you don't have a valid string on either side of the comma such as "0," or ",General" but "0,General" is valid.  Is there a way to do this with regex? (I have updated question to make clearer.)